# Is Jquery Mobile widget based on jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

If yes are there any specific constraints to fulfill for mobile ?

If no why ? Then where is the documentation to create CUSTOM widget for jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Jquery Mobile is jQuery Mobile, Jquery UI, HTML 5 Adaptations etc all rolled into 1 package. This means that when you are using `jQuery Mobile`, you are using `jQuery UI Mobile` as well. The documentation is non-existent because they've merged it all together in one mobile library for the sake of Usability. Is [THIS](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/index.html) what you want?

Answer (score 0):

It is not part of the documentation, but this is a starting point to write custom jQuery plugins: https://gist.github.com/1071960